# Pixi JS - Reference Error: Window is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, pixi.js

Im using NodeJS and Pixi JS and I have this project Ive been working on for about a month just fine, but all of a sudden I get this error below saying window is not defined.

The only thing I could find related to this issue is that Im importing pixi improperly but I never changed how I imported pixi and now all of a sudden this is the error, Im not even sure what code to share because I import pixi the same way across multiple files and it's never been changed.

If anyone could point me in the right direction your help would be appreciated

Error:

ReferenceError: window is not defined
[1]     at Object. (\node_modules@pixi\polyfill\lib\polyfill.js:16:1)

Comment: Did  you updated pixi.js node module recently? Maybe it was caused by one of recent releases? ( https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/releases )